# Different results between print_r($something) and writing the same $something in database

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I am parseing a page and saving the retrived data in mysql db. Everything is ok except the price of the product. After extracting price,when i use print_r($price) i get the actual value but while saving the same $price in my database, i get only a part of it.

for example:-
while using print_r($something);  //output is 2 458

while saving in database $something, the saved value is only  458.

I think that the problem is due to space between 2 and 4. I can understand that this is a very simple question for most of you, but right now i am not able to solve it. 
Thanks a lot ahead for support!

Comment: can you show us some sample code?

Comment: Numbers don't contain spaces, they cantain numeric characters, a leading plus or minus sign, an optional decimal point; or may be formatted with an exponential

Comment: as it's  price so it should be `float` and there should be no spaces instead there should be `.` for the number!

Comment: i am using "simple_html_dom" to parse from website and i don't know what more code can i give? the way i retrive a data or the way i print the data on page or the how i am saving the data or all of them together.....sorry if i am not getting your point of view.

Comment: truely speaking i don't know in which format i am getting the retrived value but i think it's a string value. maybe i am not true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is pretty permissive about what data you can insert into its fields. In this case you are trying to insert a string that contains two numbers into a numeric field, it's doing its best to extract a single number from that data but is getting it wrong.

All you need to do is remove the space(s) before you insert:

```
$something = str_replace(' ', '', $something);
```

or using a regular expression you could remove any non-numeric character:

```
$something = preg_replace("'[^0-9]'", '', $something);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @tim Fountain. preg_replace() function worked! Thanks a lot for quick answer. you got me in a right path.